# JavascriptSerializer exception

Tags: c#, exception, javascriptserializer

I have the following data:

> {"data":{"id":"7IaWnXo","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1397926970,"type":"image/png","animated":false,"width":60,"height":60,"size":1277,"views":0,"bandwidth":0,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"deletehash":"KYIfVnHIWWTPifh","link":"http://i.imgur.com/7IaWnXo.png"},"success":true,"status":200}

and I'm trying to serializer it into this:

```
public struct ImageInfoContainer
    {
        public ImageInfo data {get; set;}
        bool success { get; set; }
        string status { get; set; }
    }
    public struct ImageInfo
    {
        public string id {get; set;}
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string description {get; set;}
        public string datetime {get; set;}
        public string type {get; set;}
        public string animated {get; set;}
        public int width {get; set;}
        public int height {get; set;}
        public int size {get; set;}
        public int views {get; set;}
        public int bandwidth {get; set;}
        public bool favourite {get; set;}
        public bool nsfw {get; set;}
        public string section {get; set;}
        public string deletehash {get; set;}
        public string link {get; set;}
    }
```

and I'm getting:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Extensions.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot convert null to a value type.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"nsfw":null` should be `true` or `false`
`section` should be not null.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your JSON data: `nsfw` is null.
But in `ImageInfo` struct, `nsfw` is defined as a `boolean` (it **can't** be null, only `true` or `false`)

You have 2 possibilities.

- if you have access to JSON data, don't allow `null` for `nsfw`.
- use a nullable bool: `public bool? nsfw {get; set;}`

If you take second option, this will allow you to have `true`, `false` or `null` as a value for `nsfw` and you won't have this error anymore.

Both `Nullable<bool>` and `bool?` are the same syntax.
More info about [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)